# Permission denied on creating directories with cap deploy:setup

Tags: symfony, capifony

I'm trying to setup my production server for capifony. 
I've setup my deploy.rb like this:

```
set :application,   "myappname"
set :domain,        "#{application}.eu"
set :deploy_to,     "/#{application}"   # I don't know if this is correct?

default_run_options[:pty] = true
#set :repository,   "#{domain}:/var/repos/#{application}.git"
set :repository,    "/home/username/myappname"
set :scm,           :git
set :deploy_via,    :rsync_with_remote_cache

set :model_manager, "doctrine"

role :web,        domain                        
role :app,        domain                         
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       

set  :keep_releases,  3

set  :user,       "mylogintossh"
set  :use_sudo,   false
```

It's trying to create /myappname /myappname/releases /myappname/shared /myappname/shared/app/logs /myappname/shared/web/uploads

But permission is denied. 
What am I doing wrong here? :)
Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that user `mylogintossh` has permissions to create directories there? Try to login and check permissions of that directory.

As a workaround you can put your user to sudoers and set `use_sudo` to `true` or set permissions of `/myappname` to `777`.

Comment: I logged in with putty with mylogintossh and tried to create a directory and that works. I've also tried creating the /myappname dir and then doing the cap deploy:setup command but that didn't work either. The directory that I set at "deploy_to" that does equal to the root-dir that I see when I would login with filezilla, right?

Comment: Sounds, right. Create `/myappname` yourself with that user and make sure that it has permissions like 777. Does it help? If not, show more of your error message in the question.

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work. I'll post the full error message later this day.

Comment: I just tried it again and it worked. This time I was logged in as a normal non sudo user on my dev server.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
set :admin_runner, "my_apps_username"
```

in config/deploy.rb. Alternatively, you can override the deploy:setup task like this:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :setup, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    dirs = [deploy_to, releases_path, shared_path]
    dirs += shared_children.map { |d| File.join(shared_path, d.split('/').last) }
    run "mkdir -p #{dirs.join(' ')}"
    run "chmod g+w #{dirs.join(' ')}" if fetch(:group_writable, true)
  end
end
```